# Convergent series involving logarithms

Tags: calculus

So I have a test next week and I found something which I do not understand.

I probably have a wrong conclusion but I do not know where it is.

I was told that the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^{\ln(n)}}$ is convergent.

So thanks to this fact I can say that $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^2}$ is convergent (we know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{(\ln(n))^{\ln(n)}}}{ \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^2}} =1$ and thanks to [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) we can say it is also convergent).

we know that $\exists N $ $\forall n>N$ $ \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^{\ln(\ln(n))}} < \frac {1}{(\ln(n))^2}$ and therefore we can say that $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}
{(\ln(n))^{\ln(\ln(n))}}$

is also convergent (thanks to [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test)).

But I was told that $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}
{(\ln(n))^{\ln(\ln(n))}}$ is not convergent.

So where is my mistake ?

I would very appreciate any help.

All my professor are in vacation.

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: hhhhh..... I found my mistake !! the limit is zero and not one !! And this the mistake, well Thanks anyway !!

Comment: Yes, $\sum 1/\ln(n)^2$ does not converge.